# Is it possible to guarantee the order row locks are obtained across multiple UPDATE CTEs in PostgreSQL 14?

Tags: postgresql

On PostgreSQL 14

To avoid deadlocks, the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-DEADLOCKS) provides the following guidance:

> The best defense against deadlocks is generally to avoid them by being certain that all applications using a database acquire locks on multiple objects in a consistent order.

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) on CTEs states:

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable.

I assume this also means the order in which the locks are obtained for the specified updates is also unpredictable.

Does this apply even if there is a dependency between CTEs? I assumed so as I could not find any documentation that states otherwise. Perhaps because the query planer has the potential to rewrite the query in such a way that the dependency no longer exists?

I did some experimenting:

```sql
create table table_a (id int primary key, fu int);
create table table_b (id int primary key, bar int);
```

```sql
WITH update_a AS (
  UPDATE table_a
  SET fu = fu + 1
  WHERE id = 7
  RETURNING
    8 AS b_id,
    fu,
    pg_sleep(5)
),
update_b AS (
  UPDATE table_b
  SET bar = bar + 1
  FROM update_a
  WHERE id = b_id
  RETURNING
    bar,
    pg_sleep(3)
)
SELECT fu, bar FROM update_a, update_b;
```

I executed the above query and on another connection I executed:

```sql
update table_b set bar = 0; \timing on \watch 1
```

The results were:

```
UPDATE 1 |    1.392 ms
UPDATE 1 |    1.123 ms
UPDATE 1 |    1.648 ms
UPDATE 1 |    1.419 ms
UPDATE 1 | 2903.621 ms
```

Which shows the second connection was able to repeatably obtain a lock and update `table_b` without waiting for the first 5 seconds, but then had to wait to obtain the lock for ~3 seconds afterwards. This aligns with the `pg_sleep(5)` and `pg_sleep(3)` which I assume means PSQL did not lock the `table_b` row until after the `update_a` CTE completed.

However, I also noticed the `pg_locks` table contains a `RowExclusiveLock` for both `table_a` and `table_b` immediately after executing the first query, and remained the same throughout the entire 8 seconds. Though I confess to not knowing how to really read this table:

| pid | virtualtransaction | transactionid | relname | locktype | mode | granted | waitstart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2318 | 3/139 | NULL | table_a | relation | RowExclusiveLock | t | NULL |
| 2318 | 3/139 | NULL | table_a_pkey | relation | RowExclusiveLock | t | NULL |
| 2318 | 3/139 | NULL | table_b | relation | RowExclusiveLock | t | NULL |
| 2318 | 3/139 | NULL | table_b_pkey | relation | RowExclusiveLock | t | NULL |
| 2318 | 3/139 | NULL | NULL | virtualxid | ExclusiveLock | t | NULL |
| 2318 | 3/139 | 13304 | NULL | transactionid | ExclusiveLock | t | NULL |

If I rewrite the query to remove the dependency by omitting `FROM updated_b`, the behavior is inconsistent and seems to change based on table ordering in the `SELECT` statement or other factors.

Perhaps I got lucky? Again, I could not find this documented anywhere so I assume this behavior is not guaranteed.

If so, does this mean if one wanted to update two rows from **different tables** in a single query **using CTEs**, there is no way to guarantee the order the rows are locked, therefore allowing for the possibility of a deadlock?

(I realize I there are alternate solutions such using multiple queries, functions/`DO` statements, Repeatable Read isolation level, etc., but I am curious about the specific behavior of CTEs and locking order.)